# How do I increase space between Checkbox's text and the checkbox?

Tags: winforms, checkbox

I'm working with a .NET WinForms form. I'm adding a new Checkbox control to the layout, but I need its text and checkbox elements to align with existing controls. Is it possible to bump out my Checkbox's checkbox element from its text element? Or am I better off creating a separate Label control?

[image]

thanks

Comment: are you trying to achieve this programmatically? if not, why don't you just separate it with label and checkbox? Or using checkbox as a single form control and setting the autosize to false and align the checkAlign and textAlign properties as @lars mentioned as an answer.

Comment: i could use multiple controls but i like fewer controls whenever possible. plus by using the checkbox’s text it is easily clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following settings for your CheckBox controls:

```
checkBox1.AutoSize = false;
checkBox1.CheckAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
checkBox1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

You will have to set the location and the size of the control yourself now.

Comment: ah i see, so i’d widen the control to my target width, then align the text left and the check right. i’ll test this and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a custom (composite) control by adding a checkbox and a label. set the spacing as per need.